# How do I calculate integral of complex function around the circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example I have a complex function $$f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z-2)^2}$$ and a contour $$L: |z+i|=1$$ I want to find $$\oint_Lf(z)dz$$

I'm not sure about using Cauchy's integral formula as $$\oint_L \frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}\, dz = 2\pi i \cdot g(z_0)$$ with $$g(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{(z-2)^2}$$ and $$z_0=-1$$ Particularly, will not the answer depend on contour radius?

Comment: As long as that singularity is the only enclosed one, it does not care about the radius.

Comment: Are you able to use the residue theorem?

Comment: @TheCount, yes, I am

Comment: @Pavel Then you know it's just $2\pi i$ times... :-| Why would you be using Cauchy's integral formula?  It'd have to be a circle centered at $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use the residue theorem, this becomes quite an easy problem.

You care about the radius of the circle you are integrating around only insofar as it tells you whether the contour contains singularities.

In this case, you are integrating in a circle of radius 1 around $-i$. Your function is holomorphic except at 2 and -1. Neither of these poles are contained inside the disc. Thus your integral is zero.

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice.

Comment: @TheCount thank you! you'll get it next time ;)

Comment: Thank you. What should I do if any of $2$ or $-1$ falls in $L$?

Comment: Then you will need to use the residue theorem. Say your contour encloses both, then the value of the integral is $2\pi i(Res(f,2)+Res(f,-1))$